# Undefined offset: 133

Tags: php

I am trying to execute the following code

```
$datafile = fopen("Data.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

$data = array();
$singleentry = array();
fgets($datafile);
while(!feof($datafile)){
    $line=fgets($datafile);
    array_push($data,$line);
}
// the form submission data is present in $data without formating
print_r($data);
echo '<br><br><br>';

for ($i = 0; $data[$i] != "start"; $i++){
    array_push($singleentry,$data[$i]);
}
```

but i get the following error

> Undefined offset: 133
>   on the following loop

```
    for ($i = 0; $data[$i] != "start"; $i++){
    array_push($singleentry,$data[$i]);
}
```

Kindly help me resolve this issue

Comment: This would happen if there is no "start" in $data, could there be whitespaces messing with the comparison?

Comment: please use an expressive title for your question

Answer (score 0):

You can check number of read lines:

```
$linecounter = 0;
while(!feof($datafile)) {
    $line = fgets($datafile);
    array_push($data,$line);
    // We count end-of-lines
    $linecounter = $linecounter + substr_count($line, PHP_EOL);
}
...
for ($i = 0; $i < $linecounter; $i++){
    if ($data[$i] == "start" OR strpos($data[$i], "start") !== FALSE) {
        break;
    }
    array_push($singleentry,$data[$i]);
}
```